# Is "ゲーム中に使用する" a descriptor in "ゲーム中に使用する最大HPを書き写す"?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

Full text is:

```
さらに、ゲーム中に使用する最大HP、最大MP、【祝福】を書き写す。
```

I can't figure out if this is saying to copy everything during the game, or if "ゲーム中に使用する" is describing everything that needs copying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the context clearly says otherwise, ゲーム中に modifies 使用する, not 書き写す. That is, 書き写す happens before the game. I'm saying this simply because an adverbial phrase usually modifies the closest verb.

> さらに、ゲーム中に使用する最大HP、最大MP、【祝福】を書き写す。
>   In addition, copy "max HP", "max MP" and "blessing" you use during the game.

(But what's the context? A game master's guide of a tabletop RPG?)

Comment: Cool, thanks. 
(Yep, it's from the konosuba trpg)